# from: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

**from: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)
The following SMTP error was encountered: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)
quit:
The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**

below is the code for sending email in Codeigniter PHP

```
        $config = array();
        $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
        $config['wordwrap'] = 'TRUE';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['priority'] = '1';
        $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
        $config['auth'] = TRUE;
        $config['helo'] = NULL;
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp'; 
        $config['smtp_host'] = SMTP_SERVER_ADDRESS; 
        $config['smtp_user'] = SMTP_USERNAME; //$smtp_user;
        $config['smtp_pass'] = SMTP_PASSWORD; //$smtp_pass; 
        $config['smtp_port'] = SMTP_PORT_NUMBER; //$smtp_port;
        $config['smtp_auth'] = 'TRUE';
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $subject = $email_data["mail_title"];
        $message = $email_data["mail_body"];
```

How to fix this error in sending emails using google mail

Answer (score 0):

I´ve got same error 550-Invalid Helo name, but the problem was incorrect password.

Check your user+password using webmail to check if it is correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35317194)